# htaccess expression not working properly

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I'm trying to set a RewriteBase only if the hostname equals "dev.local", but my if statement doesn't seem to be working.

vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName dev.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www-shared

    Alias /frontoffice /var/www-shared/frontoffice-laravel/public

    <Directory /var/www-shared>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    <If "%{SERVER_NAME} == 'dev.local'">
        RewriteBase /frontoffice
    </If>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteBase` works only in directory context

Comment: I mean `if` directive breaks the order of `Rewrite` directives in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It works fine when I take out the If statement.

Comment: The execution order of the Apache directives may be not as they listed in the config. So `RewriteBase` with `if` may executes before the line `RewriteEngine On` or after all rewritings. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging